# Calling a method from an exported activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to android, so my apologizes if this sound foolish. Is it possible for a third party app to call any method from a publicly exported activity class (of another app)?

E.g If my app has an exported activity with public permission which anyone can call. Is it possible for any other app (possibly malicious) to use this activity and call it's method without user consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for a third party app to call any method from a publicly exported activity class (of another app)?

No. A third party app can start that activity. It cannot call arbitrary methods on it, as those methods are not themselves exported via some IPC mechanism.

The act of starting an activity will trigger certain methods to be invoked automatically (e.g., `onCreate()`). However, those methods are not being called by the other app; they are being called by the Android framework.